# IE8 removes data attributes in title elements

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

Does anyone know why IE8 removes data- attributes from title tags when it loads a page? I haven't seen this behavior in any other browser.

If you load the following html in IE8 and check the DOM in Dev tools, the data `data-title-attribute` attribute has been removed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title data-title-attribute="Damn you IE8!">Title</title>
    </head>
    <body data-body-attribute="This works!"></body>
</html>
```

Comment: I saw an answer/comment to something similar in the past that simply said "IE8 doesn't like it when you mess around with the `<title>` in any way"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little some tinkering, it looks like IE8 removes any non-HTML4 attributes from the `<title>` tag when rendering.

As a workaround it looks like you can set/add any attribute once `<title>` has been rendered into the DOM. So the following does work in my tests:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title id="title" data-title-attribute="Damn you IE8!">Title</title>
        <script>document.getElementById('title').setAttribute('data-title-attribute', 'Damn you IE8!');</script>
    </head>
    <body data-body-attribute="This works!"></body>
</html>
```

That would cause your `data-*` attribute(s) to be added to the title tag and be accessible via Javascript.

As for why it does that, I honestly think you've found a bug in IE8 because it does support `data-*` attributes in nearly every other location.

Comment: Yeah, looks like a bug. I've moved my data attribute to the <head> element instead. Thanks.